Determining the angle of a point in an image taken by a camera
Assume I have a certain picture taken aerially by a drone. The yaw, pitch, and roll of the drone gimbal are known, and so are the horizontal and vertical FoV of the camera. We also know the $x$, $y$, and $z$ coordinates the drone had while taking the picture.
In order to determine whether a point, given its $x$ and $y$ coordinates (assuming the $z$ coordinate is 0), is inside of the field of view of the image, I have been using the following algorithm:

Compute rotation matrices for yaw, pitch, and roll:

$$R_{\text{yaw}} = \begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\text{yaw}) & -\sin(\text{yaw}) & 0 \\
   \sin(\text{yaw}) & \cos(\text{yaw}) & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
$$R_{\text{pitch}} = \begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\text{pitch}) & 0 & \sin(\text{pitch}) \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   -\sin(\text{pitch}) & 0 & \cos(\text{pitch})
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
$$R_{\text{roll}} = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & \cos(\text{roll}) & -\sin(\text{roll}) \\
   0 & \sin(\text{roll}) & \cos(\text{roll})
   \end{bmatrix}
$$

Construct the combined rotation matrix (R) as the product of these three matrices:
$R = R_{\text{yaw}} \cdot R_{\text{pitch}} \cdot R_{\text{roll}}$

Compute the view vector as: \begin{bmatrix}
\text{object}_x - \text{drone}_x \\
\text{object}_y - \text{drone}_y \\
\text{object}_z - \text{drone}_z
\end{bmatrix}

Multiply $R$ by the view vector: $R \cdot view\_vector$

Calculate the vertical and horizontal angle of the object with respect to the drone point of view:


Let $t_1, t_2, t_3$ be the first, second, and third element of $R\cdot view\_vector$.
$$\theta_{\text{horizontal}} = \text{atan2}(t_2, t_1)
$$
$$\theta_{\text{vertical}} = \text{atan2}\left(t_3, \sqrt{t_1^2 + t_2^2}\right)
$$

The point is in the image if $-{fov\_horizontal \over 2} \leq \theta_{horizontal} \leq {fov\_horizontal \over 2} \land -{fov\_vertical \over 2} \leq \theta_{vertical} \leq {fov\_vertical \over 2}$. If so, we compute the relative pixels at which the object is located as:

$$
x\_rel = \frac{\theta_{horizontal} + {fov\_horizontal \over 2}}{fov\_horizontal}
$$
$$y\_rel = \frac{\theta_{vertical} + {fov\_vertical \over 2}}{fov\_vertical}
$$
Is this procedure correct? By trying it out with real numbers I don't quite get the expected results, but I'm unsure whether that's because of errors in the data or flaws in the algorithm.
